# Get the name of resource from table depending on the id

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have 2 table.

transactions (id,resourceid,timestamp)

resource (id,name)

I want to get an output like ( resource.name,day,count(transaction.id) )

I am using the following query

```
select  EXTRACT(DAY from timestamp), resourceid, count(id) from transactions
where timestamp between '01-OCT-13' AND '10-OCT-13'
and resourceid in (select id from resource)
group by resourceid, EXTRACT(DAY from timestamp) \
order by EXTRACT(DAY from timestamp);
```

Output:

```
1,1,13
1,3,45
1,6,76
2,1,14
2,2,46
```

I would like to see the output like

```
1,resource1,13
1,resource3,45
1,resource6,76
2,resource1,14
2,resource2,46
```

Can someone please help me?

**EDIT**

resource1 is just for example. I don't want to concatenate resource before the number 1. I want the actual name which is associated with id=1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you join the transactions and resouce tables then you can use the recource.name field. That might look like this:

```
select  EXTRACT(DAY from timestamp), resource.name, count(transactions.id) 
from transactions inner join resource 
    on transactions.resourceid = resource.id
where timestamp between '01-OCT-13' AND '10-OCT-13'
group by resource.name, EXTRACT(DAY from timestamp)
order by EXTRACT(DAY from timestamp);
```